# TypeScript: How to combine DefaultTheme with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components, tsx

I have a module that is made with `styled-components` and [export a theme](https://github.com/pass-culture/id-check-front/tree/master/packages/id-check/src/theme)

I want to combine the exported theme for styled from the module with my application theme.

I have tried the following in `theme.ts`:

```
import { theme as idCheckTheme } from '@pass-culture/id-check/src/theme'
import { DefaultTheme } from 'styled-components/native'
import './styled.d'

export const theme: DefaultTheme = {
  ...idCheckTheme,
  appBarHeight: 64,
}
```

I have also copied the `styled.d.ts` and added `appBarHeight: number` at the top.

When I start my application, I have the following error:

```
Property 'appBarHeight' is missing in type '{ colors: { black: ColorsEnum; error: ColorsEnum; greenValid: ColorsEnum; greyDark: ColorsEnum; greyMedium: ColorsEnum; greyLight: ColorsEnum; ... 4 more ...; primaryDark: ColorsEnum; }; typography: { ...; }; buttons: { ...; }; }' but required in type 'DefaultTheme'.  TS2741
```

I expected it to work, typing isn't complaining in IntelliJ.

How can I combine a `styled-components` theme into a new `DefaultTheme` with TypeScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should be able to extend the DefaultTheme interface, create an interface for your theme, and define it like so:

```
import { theme as idCheckTheme, ThemeType as IdCheckThemeType } from '@pass-culture/id-check/src/theme'
import { DefaultTheme } from 'styled-components/native'

// a declaration (d.ts) file may work better than declaring this above the interface
declare module 'styled-components' {
  export interface DefaultTheme extends INewTheme {}
}

export interface INewTheme extends IdCheckThemeType{
  appBarHeight: number;
}

export const NewTheme: INewTheme = {
  ...idCheckTheme,
  appBarHeight: 64,
}
 
// pass your theme to your theme provider
<ThemeProvider theme={NewTheme}>
<App/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

inside your styled components, you should also be able to access the appBarHeight like this:

```
const StyledBar = styled.div`
  ${({theme}) => theme.appBarHeight};
`
```

Comment: Don't you need to also import the `IdCheckTheme` typing in order to create `INewTheme` ? Otherwise, how does the `idCheckTheme` type will be loaded ?

Comment: From the application, I have an error detected in the module using the solution you mentionned : `src/ui/components/buttons/ButtonPrimary.tsx
TypeScript error in src/ui/components/buttons/ButtonPrimary.tsx(21,3):
Type 'ThemeType' is not assignable to type 'DefaultTheme'.  TS2322`

Comment: After assigning the theme of the package to the newly created type instead of `DefaultTheme`, I am able to start the app. But I MUST set all the variablse from the application theme type optional : https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/77674046/131313431-227b2361-23f6-41a2-b6c1-8e77bbf6ec9f.png  This is not very conveniant, is there a way to tell typescript not to check the package ?

Comment: i've edited my answer to include extending the ThemeType as well. 

is it required that you provide the theme as a defaultProp to each component? are you able to access theme.buttons.primary within your styles file?

what version of react are you on? alternatively, instead of useTheme, can you use ThemeContext and useContext hook: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#via-usecontext-react-hook

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had the same problem when I was upgrading a NextJS file to V12. I kept having that problem and finally figured out what was causing it.

My `tsconfig.json` file had a value `"incremental": true`. When I looked it up, I saw that it saves previous compilation files and then "incrementally" builds your executable using those saved files as a starting point. As soon as I removed that option, my build and tests worked perfectly.

I'm guessing there were some old compilation files that Typescript didn't know to throw away and that was causing the problem?

Crasy, but it sure solved my issue.